# Multithreading in PyQt5

Tags: multithreading, pyqt5, signals-slots

Imagine the below case. buttonClickEvent() function is started when a QPushButton is clicked and this function has 2 threads(thread 1 and thread 2) and each thread has a signal. I have a function which takes the inputs from the 2 signals(thread_1.signal, thread_2.signal). How do I connect the function's execution to run only when both the threads finished executing.(Please consider the question is from an amateur programmer and please explain in layman's terms).

```
buttonClickEvent():
    thread_1()
    thread_2()
    function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create handler with slots that receives and stores data and checks if both values received.

```py
class Handler:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data1 = None
        self._data2 = None
    def _process(self):
        if None in [self._data1, self._data2]:
            return
        # your code here
    def onData1(self, data):
        self._data1 = data
        self._process()
    def onData2(self, data)
        self._data2 = data
        self._process()

handler = Handler()
thread_1.signal.connect(handler.onData1)
thread_2.signal.connect(handler.onData2)
```